# Running a python script that logs into a spark EC2 cluster and then runs a script.

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there documentation on running a script that can log into a spark cluster and run a script? I've been able to launch clusters with Linux Bash scripts but I'm wondering if there is anything more general (python would be great). I would like to have a script that reads certain parameters and then runs them automatically without having to have the user log in. I want this to be as easy and intuitive as possible (so someone less tech savy can just start the script without having to worry about dealing with spark or AWS) or be able to run in the background of a web app.

Comment: Fabric (http://www.fabfile.org) is great for running tasks on a remote cluster.

Comment: Fabric seems great But I can't find any good examples. It seems like using a run command is what I need but then how would determine the server that I'm running on. So I'd need something like: `local( spark-ec2 -k EC2KEY)` `Run Shell Commands`